# Mixing REST with non RESTful API calls

Tags: php, laravel, rest, https, crud

I'm in the process of writing a RESTful API. For the most part, everything works out great but there are a few cases when I'm not dealing with a resource that things start to break down. While there are a million ways to solve the problem I'm facing, I'm looking for some feedback as to which would be the most ideal.

For simplicity, we'll say that the API is a `timer`.

- A user can only have 1 active `timer` at a time.
- The API has 2 functional endpoints `start` and `stop`.
- When the user `start`s the timer they `POST` some data related to the `timer` which creates a new `timer` as long as they don't already have a `timer` running.
- Calling `stop` on the `timer` updates the `timer` to mark it inactive.

I currently have this setup as follows:

Start Timer:

```
POST /api/v1/timer
Body: [
    'thing1' => 'something',
    'thing2' => 'somethingelse
]

Response: 204
```

Stop Timer:

```
PUT /api/v1/timer/stop
Body:

Response: 204
```

Since a user can only have 1 `timer` active, it didn't seem to make sense to return the `timer` `id` as you would in a more traditional CRUD call.

I've read some posts that suggest using `POST` method on the `stop` call to trigger the stop instead of a `PUT`. I suppose that makes sense too... this just really breaks down when you're not dealing with a traditional resource.

Of course, I could also rewrite it to return a `timer` resource but to me that adds overhead of the client having to then track the `timer` `id` when they want to stop (or delete) the active timer.

Any input here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about how you would implement this requirement on a website.

You would be looking at some web page, specific to the current user.  There would be a link labeled start.  You would get that link, and it would bring up a form that gives you the ability to override the default parameters associated with starting the timer.

When you submit the form, the browser would construct a request based on the HTML form processing rules.  Since this isn't a safe operation, the method would probably be a post, and the form data would be application/x-www-form-urlencoded into the message body.

Since changing the state of the timer would probably change the representation of the original page, that's likely where the form would tell you to submit the POST.  A successful response to the POST request would tell the browser to invalidate it's cached representation of the original page.

When you reload that page, the "start" link would be gone, and there would instead be a "stop" link.  The operation of that link would be much the same --> clicking the link takes you to a form, submitting the form back to the original page, invalidating the previous representation.  When you reload the page, the timer is off and the start link is available again.

```
GET /DarthVaderYellowMerrigold

GET /DarthVaderYellowMerrigold/start
POST /DarthVaderYellowMerrigold
GET /DarthVaderYellowMerrigold

GET /DarthVaderYellowMerrigold/stop
POST /DarthVaderYellowMerrigold
GET /DarthVaderYellowMerrigold
```

There are various things you might do to clean this up (returning the new representation in response to a successful POST, for example, with the appropriate Content-Location headers, so that the client doesn't need to fetch the data), but the basic idea is sound.

Do that in a machine readable way, and you have yourself a REST API.

Doing that mostly means documenting how the machine is supposed to understand what each link is for.  "To go to the start timer form, look for this link; to go to the stop timer form, look for that link".

You'll probably leave HTTP and URI alone, but it's reasonable to replace HTML with, for example, one of the hypermedia JSON types.  Or to put the links into the HTML headers, rather than in the representation.

Of course, HTML has the immediate advantage that you can just walk the API "by hand" and make sure that everything works using your favorite desktop browser.  Trade-offs abound.

Comment: I guess I should clarify that this is a OAuth2 API. This won't be used or consumed by HTML.